# DNS address of intranet server could not be found

Tags: 16.04, apache2, dns, dnsmasq, intranet

I have set up an intranet server running ubuntu 16.04, apache2 and dnsmasq.
On the ubuntu system everything is working fine. On my second system (Windows 10) i get an ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED error in Chrome and a similar one in Edge while trying to access the Server via its domain name. Connecting to the ip address works fine. I also tested pinging the domain via console and got the following return:

> Ping wird ausgeführt für nextcloud.intranet [192.168.2.199] mit 32 Bytes Daten:
>   Antwort von 192.168.2.199: Bytes=32 Zeit<1ms TTL=128
>   Antwort von 192.168.2.199: Bytes=32 Zeit<1ms TTL=128
>   Antwort von 192.168.2.199: Bytes=32 Zeit<1ms TTL=128
>   Antwort von 192.168.2.199: Bytes=32 Zeit<1ms TTL=128

So i assume the dns server is working, but why are my browsers unable to connect?

The Server has a static ip address (192.168.2.199) with the router (easybox) configured to use this server as its primary dns and 8.8.8.8 as its secondary.
dnsmasq is listening on 127.0.0.1/192.168.2.199 and is configured to force every *.intranet domain on 192.168.2.199 (address=/.intranet/192.168.2.199).

> dns=dnsmasq

is commented out for the NetworkManager.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding my Servers static ip address to it's host file solved the problem.

> /etc/hosts
>
> 127.0.0.1     myServer
>   192.168.2.199 myServer